# Why does Windows Explorer display a bogus updated time, and is there a way to recalibrate its datetimostat?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, windows-xp-mode, date-time

Here is my process when testing a Windows CE app:

1. Rebuild it to create new .exe/.dll pairs from the two projects in the solution (`PDAClient.exe` and `HUtilCE.dll`).
2. Since I have to do this development in XP Mode using prehistoric libraries and tools (.NET 1.1, Visual Studio 2003), I then copy those two files from the `\debug` folder within the XP Mode to a folder on my Windows 7 machine that is visible/mapped to the XP Mode Windows Explorer.
   *When I do so, the files copied display the correct timestamp in XP Mode Windows Explorer* (such as `7/29/2013 11:01 am`)
3. I then go into W7 Windows Explorer so as to copy the files from that folder to the Windows CE device. There, though, the timestamp for these files display a blast from the past (`7/10/2013 11:37 am`)
4. I then copy and paste those files from W7 Explorer to the Windows CE device; there they display the correct timestamp (`7/29/2013 11:01 am`).

Why does only the middleman (Windows 7) display a bogus timestamp, and how can I give it a nudge to wake up and smell the fresh coffee?